PostGIS Clustering Issue
I am attempting to write a function which will use PostGIS to group geometric points based off the bounding box passed to the function.
I created the following table:
CREATE TABLE items (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    location GEOMETRY(Point, 4326)  -- SRID 4326 for geographic coordinates
);

And populated it with random data within a specified bounding box using the following code:
DO
$$
DECLARE
    i INT := 0;
    min_lat FLOAT := 54.542;
    max_lat FLOAT := 54.559;
    min_lon FLOAT := -5.761;
    max_lon FLOAT := -5.729;
    rand_lat FLOAT;
    rand_lon FLOAT;
BEGIN
    WHILE i < 1000 LOOP
        -- Generate random latitude and longitude within the bounding box
        rand_lat := min_lat + (max_lat - min_lat) * random();
        rand_lon := min_lon + (max_lon - min_lon) * random();
        
        -- Insert a new row with the generated location
        INSERT INTO items (location)
        VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(rand_lon, rand_lat), 4326));

        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;

The function to perform the clustering looks like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_items_within_bbox(
    min_x FLOAT, 
    min_y FLOAT, 
    max_x FLOAT, 
    max_y FLOAT, 
    cluster_distance FLOAT
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    item_id INT, 
    cluster_id BIGINT, 
    cluster_geom GEOMETRY, 
    cluster_count BIGINT
) AS $$
DECLARE
    bbox GEOMETRY;
BEGIN
    -- Create the bounding box geometry
    bbox := ST_MakeEnvelope(min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y, 4326);

    RETURN QUERY
    WITH items_in_bbox AS (
        SELECT 
            i.id AS item_id, 
            i.location AS item_location
        FROM items i
        WHERE ST_Intersects(i.location, bbox) 
    ),
    clusters AS (
        SELECT 
            unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(item_location, cluster_distance)) AS cluster_geom
        FROM items_in_bbox
    ),
    cluster_points AS (
        SELECT 
            i.item_id AS point_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS point_cluster_id, 
            c.cluster_geom AS cluster_geom
        FROM items_in_bbox i
        JOIN clusters c ON ST_Intersects(i.item_location, c.cluster_geom) 
    ),
    cluster_counts AS (
        SELECT 
            cp.point_cluster_id AS cluster_id, 
            COUNT(*) AS cluster_count 
        FROM cluster_points cp
        GROUP BY cp.point_cluster_id
    )
    SELECT 
        MIN(cp.point_id) AS item_id,  
        cp.point_cluster_id AS cluster_id, 
        ST_Collect(cp.cluster_geom) AS cluster_geom,  
        cc.cluster_count AS cluster_count
    FROM cluster_points cp
    JOIN cluster_counts cc ON cp.point_cluster_id = cc.cluster_id 
    GROUP BY cp.point_cluster_id, cc.cluster_count; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

I then attempt to call the function using:
SELECT * FROM get_items_within_bbox(
    -5.761,  -- min_x (West Longitude)
    54.542,  -- min_y (South Latitude)
    -5.729,  -- max_x (East Longitude)
    54.559,  -- max_y (North Latitude)
    1609.34  -- cluster_distance in meters
);

No matter what value I supply for the cluster_distance, I always get 1000 rows of data returned and the cluster_count of each item is always 1.

You are working with Geometry type, so PostGIS computes all distances as Cartesian, in particular case in meaningless distance in degrees. So all distances are way below the 1609 you give to it (which PostGIS interprets not as meters, but as same units you pass to st_makepoint):
# select st_distance(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-5.761, 54.542), 4326),
                     st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-5.729,  54.559), 4326));
     st_distance      
----------------------
 0.036235341863984985
(1 row)

For PostGIS the SRID only matters when you try to convert to another projection, using ST_Transform, but not when computing distances. ST_ClusterWithin doc specifically mentions this: Distances are Cartesian distances in the units of the SRID.
PostGIS did not implement clustering algorithms for Geography type (which does proper distance computations). So to do clustering in meters in PostGIS, you would probably need to transform data to a suitable projection first.
Alternatively, use some system that implements clustering for Geography type. E.g. Google BigQuery has ST_ClusterDBSCAN. ST_ClusterWithin is equivalent to running ST_ClusterDBSCAN with minpoints => 0.
